# Beacon testing Microchip RN4871

Tags: bluetooth, microchip, bluetooth-low-energy

I got a Microchip RN4871 BLE Module and want it to act as beacon.

So, I connected over UART and executed the following commands:

```
SS,20
SC,2
NB,09,656667
```

Whether I have configured the beacon properly. Which is the beacon format supported by Microchip. (iBeacon, EddyStone ). If iBeacon, how can I set the UUID, Major, Minor Number and TX Power..

Did anyone has success in using RN4871 Devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get RN4871 as Beacon..

I executed the following command over Serial ( TeraTerm ). Set it into Command Mode.

```
IB,Z
IB,FF,4C000215AD11CF40063F11E5BE3E0002A5D5C51B000C000DC5
```

Verified using ‘iBeacon & Eddystone Scanner Application’.